# Web browser cannot find pages after machine "sleeping" and "waking up" several times.

Tags: windows-7, internet, browser

At night before I go to sleep, i have a habit of putting my laptop to Sleep instead of completely shutting it off. But after a few days of "sleeping" and "waking up" without restarting. my browser starts malfunctioning. It wouldn't open pages. If I try to reload, sometimes the browser reloads part of the page. This behavior can be fixed only by restarting Windows. Is there a solution to fix this without restarting my PC?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @Jikag chome, firefox, internet explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this before on laptops where the wireless adapter would be turned off to save power but not come back on, which could be the same problem you have.

To stop the wireless being disabled open Control Panel and go to the network section, right click the adapter and select "Properties" and click the "Configure" button. In the "Properties" dialog window select the "Power Management" option and uncheck the box "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power".

Comment: it doesn't seem like the adapter was completely turned off because when i tried refreshing, sometimes i get a page partially loaded...

Comment: Is your laptop also plugged into Ethernet? I've seen weird issues where it's plugged into both and then one or the other goes offline and then comes back.

Comment: @Jikag laptop accesses the internet wirelessly